# Facebook api - get the albums and the photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I looked for an example of a simple asp.net mvc application which only shows the albums and the pictures they contain via facebook api. Unfortunately I didn't find a worthwhile example.

I visited facebook and read the guilds for developers but in fact I even didn't understand what kind of api I should use: Javascript SDK, Open Graph API or just Graph API. I already created my test application at https://developers.facebook.com/apps.

Does anybody can help me to solve this issue?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Facebook C# SDK - they have an example of a web app on their website: [Getting Started with the Facebook C# SDK for ASP.NET](http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started)